# Source Tree 1 branch ahead and 1 branch behind

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem with my SourceTree repository. I don't know what I did but now I have 1 branch behind and 1 branch ahead. And if I try to pull I get error which is saying that I have uncommitted changes (but I dont have any) and if I try to push I get error and is saying that I need to pull first.
If I try to merge my branch I also get error which is saying: "fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).Please, commit your changes before you merge."

Here is a picture:

[image]

And here is a video:
http://recordit.co/MYOgeSFTaD

Thank you for your time !

Comment: what happens when you press fetch button? Try having a look at this [answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-resolve-when-master-is-behind-origin-master-and-develop/qaq-p/349994)

Comment: I upload a video to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by pressing the Commit button and after I checked "Push changes immediately to origin" and effectively I commit nothing (0 files). But there was created a connection between the branch and master and now I don't have anymore errors. I don't know if is normal or not but this fixed my problem.
Here is a photo so you can compare the first photo with this one:

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Your distant `origin/master` and your local `master` are both 1 commit ahead.

**1 behind** means the *distant repo* is 1 commit further from your common base
**1 ahead** means your *local workspace* is 1 commit further from your common base

If you want to push your modifications you have to catch up distant commits *(1 behind)* and merge it with your local modifications *(1 ahead)*. Press **Pull**, if there's no conflict *(your edits aren't located at the same place as theirs)* it creates a new commit for you, else you'll have to solve those conflicts first.

You'll then be 2 ahead but no longer behind. You can't push with commits behind. Just push your modifications.

---

I edit this after watching your video. There's conflicts in your workspace. Just click on **File Status** on the left side bar and solve these conflicts.
Then commit, then push, as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue, the solution that I went for and worked fine is:

1 - Stashed changes for remaining on the safe side

2 - Took backup for remaining at the safer zone :)

3 - Then discarded all the changes showing up in the commit area -> Top left button in the source tree.

4 - Pull and merge changes first. Then push your changes. Everything will be aligned.